# What are some good books I can use to learn Algebra 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like some suggestions on some good books to learn Algebra 1. This is my first time learning the topic but I already know some of the topics (ex. Linear Equations and Real Numbers). Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Edit: By Algebra 1 I mean the subject that's taught in high school usually in either 8th or 9th grade.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! By algebra, what do you mean? Classical, Abstract or linear? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What exactly does "algebra 1" entail? Different universities define the term differently.

Comment: @MarkSaving I just finished teaching a graduate course on commutative algebra and Galois theory this semester. The course appears in the catalog as "Algebra I"!

Comment: I found "Elements of Abstract Algebra" by Allan Clark accessible for self-study.

Comment: Algebra goes from middle school to graduate school and beyond. Are you asking for a high school level book? When you say "Linear Equations" do you mean systems of linear equations or $y=mx+b$?

Comment: @pmun I mean the Algebra 1 the type that you learn in high school not college. It includes topic such as Linear Equations, Systems of Equations, and Quadratics.

Comment: @MarkSaving I actually mean high school Algebra 1. I'm not in university and just want to get ahead in math. Topics in Algebra 1 include: Polynomials, Linear Equations, Graphing of Linear equations, Functions, Systems of Equations, and Quadratics.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yeah I'm asking for a high school level book. And types of Linear equations like slope-intercept form, point-slope form, and standard form.

Comment: @nmasanta I clicked on the link and I don't find any of the books on that thread relevant to what i'm looking for. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I have been out of high school for a long time and I haven't taught in a while either so I am out of touch. For questions like these you really need to be specific. If you are taking a course your instructor is the best person to recommend a book. If you have a book that doesn't work for you then you should specify that in your question so those who want to answer know what to recommend.

Comment: @JohnDouma Sorry for being too vague. I'm going to take high school Algebra 1 next year and I want to get ahead. I haven't been assigned any textbooks to study from. I made this post to ask if anyone had any suggestions for books that I could use to learn it.

Comment: Try contacting your high school and ask if they can recommend a book. They may also let you borrow one for the summer. Teachers like students who want to get ahead.

Comment: @JohnDouma Ok, Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I haven't read it, but I think Gelfand's book [Algebra](https://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Israel-M-Gelfand/dp/0817636773) which teaches high school algebra looks good.

Comment: Art of Problem Solving's book [Introduction to Algebra](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/item/intro-algebra) is probably also good. But it might contain some very challenging Olympiad level problems, so you must not get discouraged if a lot of the problems seem very hard. The problems are likely much more difficult than the routine exercises you find in a typical high school algebra book.

Answer (score 1):

Back when I was teaching we used to use K. Elayne Martin-Gay.  Kaufman was also a text that I used.  The exposition was pretty good and there were plenty of problems.

In junior high I remember using books by Dolciani et al.